# multiple arbitrary blocks in Jinja2 macros

Tags: jinja2, nunjucks

I use both Jinja2 and Nunjucks (depending on the project), but have yet to figure out how to create reusable elements with *multiple* blocks containing *arbitrary HTML*. For example (pseudo-code):

```
{% macro item(class) %}
    <article class="{{ class }}">
        <h3>{{ caller(1) }}</h3>
        <p>{{ caller(2) }}</p>
    </article>
{% endmacro %}

{% call item %}
    Hello <abbr title="...">world</abbr>!
    {% ---- %}
    lorem <em>ipsum</em> dolor <strong>sit</strong> amet
{% endcall %}
```

Passing the respective blocks' HTML as regular arguments (i.e. strings) to the macro seems unrealistic.

A less contrived example might be Bootstrap-style forms:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="{{ id }}" class="control-label">$label</label>
    <input type="{{ type }}" id="{{ id }}">
    <p class="help-block">$hint</p>
</div>
```

Here both `$label` and `$hint` might be arbitrary blocks of HTML - perhaps there might even be multiple fields, defined outside the macro.

What's the recommended approach here?

Comment: It's unclear to me what you want to achieve. What do you want to obtain, and what should the code to obtain it ideally look like?

Answer (score 0):

You might find this useful for re-usable HTML components:

```
https://github.com/mozilla/nunjucks/pull/277
```

Example:

```
{% include 'search-box.html.twig' with {placeholder: 'Search users'} %}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [embed tag](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/embed.html) of [atpl](https://github.com/soywiz/atpl.js) template engine.
Example:

```
{% embed "teasers_skeleton.twig" %}
    {# These blocks are defined in "teasers_skeleton.twig" #}
    {# and we override them right here:                    #}
    {% block label %}
        Some content for the label box
    {% endblock %}
    {% block hint %}
        Some content for the hint box
    {% endblock %}
{% endembed %}
```

Comment: That looks close to what I want - I'm just not sure I can easily port my existing Nunjucks projects to atpl; it's certainly worth a try. Of course that won't help me with Python's Jinja2 though...

Comment: "Use a different templating engine" is not a very good/reasonable answer 